# Run Salt minion specifying the Python path

Tags: python, salt-stack

Is there any way to specify the python interpreter that has to be used to run the salt-minion?

I have several salt minions running on a local network.
Most of them are working correctly but some minions are throwing errors and our guess is that the minion is running with python 3 instead of python 2 (we need to use `salt-2018.3.4-py2`)

If I run `python --version` it says the version is 3.7. How can we force the minion to use python 2.7?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have version 2.7 installed?

Comment: Show the errors you are getting: don't guess

Comment: What does `python --version` say for the working minions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it directly depends on your installation package. If you installed `salt-2018.3.4-py2` it means it will run with py2.

On my minion, salt-2019.2-py3 is installed and I have

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
$ salt-minion --versions
Salt Version:
           Salt: 2019.2.0

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: Not Installed
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: 2.5.3
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: 2.0.0
      gitpython: 2.1.1
          ioflo: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.9.4
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.8
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.12
          PyZMQ: 16.0.2
           RAET: Not Installed
          smmap: 2.0.1
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.4.3
            ZMQ: 4.2.1

System Versions:
           dist: debian 9.9 
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.9.0-9-amd64
         system: Linux
        version: debian 9.9
```

and

```
$ head -1 /usr/bin/salt-minion 
#!/usr/bin/python3
```